# Getting IR signal from remote controller

Tags: infrared

I was trying to get a IR signal from a remote controller.

I hooked the IR receiver to the oscilloscope and I got nothing. Then I brought the remote controller very close (~1 mm from the receiver) and I started getting a signal, but it was random (with another controller that I have, if I hold one button, it first sends the button code and then a constant value; this doesn't happen with the other controller).

I disassembled the controller; this is all the information I got:

- XWDB-1106
- LXZK-TX1021-v1.0
- (cristal oscillator) NDR4208 (I think it ends with "i1", I'm not sure)

The receiver I'm using is the [VS1838B](https://www.elecrow.com/download/Infrared%20receiver%20vs1838b.pdf).

[image: Schematic]

Maybe the controller's frequency is not the same as the receiver's?

Edit: **The remote controller was RF, not IR**.

Comment: 1) include links to datasheets 2) include a **schematic** of your setup (yes even when it is "obvious"). On this site we like schematics so include one.

Comment: What voltage supply did you power the VS1838B with?

Comment: Some receivers need a pull-up resistor.   Try another remote, you can check them with a camera with poor IR filtering, eg webcam, most non-apple phones, etc.

Comment: Most likely you have connected the VS1838B wrong. Show how you connected it and we can check.

Comment: I've added a datasheet (all I found was in chinese) and the schematic. Beside the 100uF capacitor (which I think it's a lot, but it's what the datasheet says) I don't think I have anything connected wrong. Also, have in mind that the circuit works with another controller.

Comment: I have tryed what @ChrisStratton says and I have realized that the controller has a red LED (it's clearly visible). I guess the controller uses something else to turn on the device...

Comment: Incidentally you can often snoop the pulse coding of an OOK RF remote if you power it through a small resistor and watch the voltage on that with a scope.  Or it's a great excuse to buy an RTL-SDR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this FCC test report](https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/2AUSN-LXZK1021/4490455.pdf) for the LXZK-TX1021 remote control, this remote uses HF at 433.92 MHz.

In other words: it is not an IR remote; it uses radio, so it does not send any IR you can receive.

It did pass the test, though.

Apart from that, you should put a >20 kΩ pull-up resistor between 5 V and Out, and a small cap in parallel with the 100 μF, both as described in the datasheet, if you want to wire the receiver up correctly.

Comment: Of course the wiring of the IR receiver was _also_ wrong, lacking the pull-up resistor.  Kind of interesting that when really close there was apparently some interference coupling to either the receiver or the scope probe.

Comment: If I buy a receiver (let's say, [this decoding module](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32650163262.html)) would I be able to get the same signal? I connected the original receiver signal to a oscilloscope and I got 400ns 5V, 750ns 0V (OFF); 750ns 5V, 400ns 0V (ON).